# How to enable ES6 in JSFiddle for browsers which don't support ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsfiddle

How can I enable ES6 in JSFiddle for browsers which don't support ES6 (like IE)?

Comment: Have a look at the [compat-table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just click the JavaScript gear in the bottom-right window, and change the Language setting from JavaScript to Babel:

[image]

Comment: While this answer is true, I'd rather have this question closed. (It's being discussed on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340292/how-can-i-improve-this-question-better-tagging-perhaps))

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't think this question should be closed. See [my answer on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340339/3853934).

Comment: @Cerbrus I'd be thankful if you had time to shed some light on the reason why you think this question should be closed. Feel free to follow it up on Meta.

Comment: Because it's a question for JSFiddle support. Not for SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus JSFiddle is a tool used by programmers for programming, so it is definitely on-topic.

Comment: Visual Studio is a tool used by programmers for programming, but _"How to open a solution"_ Is still a off-topic question.

Comment: @Cerbrus But "*how to open a solution so that it automatically creates a Core project?*" might be on-topic, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Cerbrus The question's been upvoted, downvoted, closed, reopened. I'm seriously considering removing the whole thing all together. It's passed silly and is bordering on ridiculous.

Comment: I'd argue that belongs on Super User, @KonradViltersten, if on SE at all. Did this question _really_ __have__ to be re-opened?

Comment: @Cerbrus How come that **closing** a question (which I oppose) is motivated by *community decision, 5 votes minimum* but **reopening** it (still minimum 5 votes, community decision) is frowned upon? (I don't refer to your comment specifically - I've seen that quite a few times before. Hence me asking.)

Comment: 2 out of 5 re-open votes are by users that are involved in the question. Those votes _are_ biased. With questions like these, what value do they _really_ add to SO that we have to keep them around? You _know_ the question isn't very good, it's received quite a few downvotes, yet you're apparently determined to keep it around.

Comment: @Cerbrus I see your point about the 2 of 5. However, just because we're involved, it doesn't mean we're biased. We **might** be biased but you have no means nor mandate to determine that. Just as the other side might be biased by something irrelevant. **Might**. We can't know for sure, hence the voting. Also, the claim that I **know** that the question isn't very good seems very strong. In fact, I think that the question is good (10 upvotes) and serves a purpose. I really don't intend to cause any infected discussion but I feel that only opinion aligned to one side is regarded as respectable.

Comment: If you didn't know the question isn't very good, why did you ask a meta question about improving it? Those 10 upvotes are accompanied by 17 downvotes, at this moment...

Comment: @Cerbrus I did so because I try to be humble and improve to satisfy others. Please be aware that **if** I though the question wasn't good, I wouldn't ask how to improve it. I'd simply improve it. Me asking on Meta is due to the surprise and lack of understanding how a question that is (in my view) good was downvoted by (incorrect) voting. I was trying to go the extra file to satisfy even the users whose opinion I didn't agre with. It's more polite to say "*how can I improve this*" than "*my questions got bashed wrongly*". Don't you agree?